# upgrading R version 3.3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, r

I am currently using R version 3.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I am trying to install a package in R called kma which requires packages like devtools, data.table etc. When I try to install these packages, I get this :

```
install.packages(c("devtools", "data.table", "reshape2", "dplyr"))
Warning in install.packages :
  download had nonzero exit status
Installing packages into ‘/home/varun/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  packages ‘devtools’, ‘data.table’, ‘reshape2’, ‘dplyr’ are not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

These packages are installed without any problems if the R version is 3.3 or above. How can I upgrade my R to version 3.3 or above from my current version of 3.2. Also all my packages are in 3.2. Do I have to install all these packages again?

Hope to hear soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

## Use [Michael Rutter's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rrutter)

Rutter's PPA currently has R 3.4.0. To install the PPA open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This will upgrade your R installation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi
I upgraded my R version to 3.4. Since I am running R using Rstudio , I am trying to install bioconductor for 3.4 version but I am getting this error 
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
  URL 'https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R': status was 'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates'


How can I fix this??

Comment: @user3138373 I have no idea about bioconductor. This looks like their website problem.  Please ask a new question so others may help. If you are satisfied with my answer above consider accepting the answer as correct and put the green check mark against it. Thanks.

Comment: I installed R 3.4 from a tarball, but can't seem to get Ubuntu to recognize it... I can follow this command but would prefer to just have apt recognize the new install / not have to redownload etc. any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Ubuntu to recognize it". If you want a launcher icon, you will have to do that yourself. That's how a tarball works. They also  don't update by themselves. It is easier to delete the installation and start again. Please ask a new question with more details.